# Pretty print a dictionary matrix in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Giving a dictionary of dictionary:

```
dict_2d = collections.defaultdict(dict)

dict_2d['A']['A'] = 1
dict_2d['A']['B'] = 0.19
...
dict_2d['Z']['A'] = 0.76
...
dict_2d['Z']['Z'] = 1
```

Could you advise an elegant way to print such a square matrix?

For instance:

1. is there a way to map or print it like a pandas.Dataframe?

[image]

2. is there a way to print it like an heatmap, with Strings as indexes? https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/matshow.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-matshow-py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you first question:
the easiest way would be to convert your 2D dict to a dataframe and to print it:

```
import collections
import pandas as pd

dict_2d = collections.defaultdict(dict)

dict_2d['A']['A'] = 1
dict_2d['A']['B'] = 0.19
dict_2d['B']['B'] = 2
dict_2d['Z']['A'] = 0.76

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_2d,orient='index')
```

Output (in shell):

```
      A     B
A  1.00  0.19
Z  0.76   NaN
B   NaN  0.19
```

For the second one:
you can use `seaborn` with `matplotlib`:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.heatmap(df);
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: python nested dict to heatmap]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly how your print should look like however I tried writing some code. I would recommend using `tabulate` or `pandas` as it makes it way easier.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_2d)
print(df)

#       A     Z
# A  1.00  0.76
# B  0.19   NaN
# Z   NaN  1.00
```

I will attach my quick attempt on making something similar. The code is quite ugly and the columns and rows are flipped compared to pandas's print.

```
def pp(d):
    s = "\t"
    keys = set([k for values in d.values() for k in values])
    s += "\t".join(keys) + "\n"
    for key, value in d.items():
        s += key + "\t"
        for k in keys:
            s += str(d[key].get(k)) + "\t"
        s += "\n"

    print(s)
#      A     B      Z
# A    1     0.19   None    
# Z    0.76  None   1
```